# RedBean Получить сумму значений из нескольких строк

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Как получить сумму значений из нескольких строк.
Пример: Таблица имеет следующие поля ID, product_id, rating

```
1 1 5
2 1 4
3 1 4
4 1 3
5 2 5
6 2 3
7 2 4
8 2 3
9 2 3
```

Нужно получить сумму значений rating где product_id = 1

Comment: `R::get('SELECT sum(rating) FROM table WHERE product_id = ?', [1])`?

Comment: метод get не найден

Comment: Там ещё getAll есть вроде